# How can I create multipart tar file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

How can I create a multipart tar file in Linux?

Comment: Related [How to split a tar file into smaller parts at file boundaries?](http://superuser.com/questions/189691/how-to-split-a-tar-file-into-smaller-parts-at-file-boundaries)

Comment: Similar, but not the same. The linked question @Sathya points to is more complex and requires a more complicated solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `split` command to split an archive in to multiple files. For example, if I wanted my archive stored in 1 MByte files:

```
tar -cvf - <stuff to put in archive> | split --bytes=1m --suffix-length=4 --numeric-suffix - myarchive.tar.
```

And when I want to recombine and untar:

```
cat myarchive.tar.* | tar xvf -
```

Comment: in gnu split, --numeric-suffixes is the param.

Answer (score 4):

GNU Tar natively [supports multiple volumes](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Multi_002dVolume-Archives.html). There are many options, the one I found neat was

```
tar --create --multi-volume --file=/tmp/file1.tar --file=/tmp/file2.tar files_to_archive
```

size can be specified via -L (tape-length)

It does not support compression in this manner however, so you would have to seperately do that. "tar: Cannot use multi-volume compressed archives"

Answer (score 0):

Use `tar c` to create the tar archive, and specify the `k size-in-kbytes` parameter to control the maximum size of each part. You'll end up with ((original size)/(part size) + 1) parts.

Comment: Where did you get the "k size-in-kbytes parameter"? Can't seem to find it on Linux.

Comment: saw it here: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utar.htm

Comment: Not in Gentoo linux, unfortunately.

Comment: Arch Linux, `tar (GNU tar) 1.29`, I see no such option too.