# Error when recombining multipart TAR file

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint, tar

I created a multipart tar file based on the instructions in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/198868/1811260). But when I try to recombine and untar, I'm getting an error message.

To create a multipart tar from a large directory, I did the following:

```
tar -cvf - <stuff to put in archive> | split --bytes=1m --suffix-length=4 --numeric-suffix - myarchive.tar.
```

This command produced two files, one ending in tar.00 and another ending in tar.01. In the Linux Mint graphical file explorer, the file ending in tar.00 is classified as an archive file, while the file ending in tar.01 is classified as a binary file.

To recombine and untar the two tar.* files, I did the following:

```
cat myarchive.tar.* | tar xvf -
```

But the second command is giving me this error message:

```
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I'm not sure if there was a problem with the multipart tar, or if the command to recombine the files was incorrect.

Comment: Did it tell you what the "previous errors" were? Redirecting stderr of the unfortunate `tar` to a regular file or running this `tar` without `v` should allow you to spot all error messages, not just the last one.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot

Comment: You could also try to be more specific and break up the commands to troubleshoot.  It is more specific than throwing down the wildcards.  `cat myarchive.tar.00 myarchive.tar.01 >myarchive_final.tar` .. then try to untar said ball.  I didn't test my commands so if I made a mistake forgive me.  When I am having a problem, breaking down the steps often makes the failure clear.